# Problem using TypeDescriptor and PropertyDescriptor to add up Counts of properties of type IReadOnlyList<(string, int)>

Tags: c#, reflection, typedescriptor, propertydescriptor

I have a class, `Container` which has many `IReadOnlyList<(string, int)>` properties on it.

It also has a `TotalCount` property which is the total count of ALL these lists.

Of course I could simply return list1.Count + list2.Count … but I wanted to see if I could do it more compactly using `TypeDescriptor` and `PropertyDescriptor`.

The problem seems to be that the `listProperties` variable is not right, but I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Here is my code:

```
   public class Container
    {

        public IReadOnlyList<(string name, int id)> List1 { get; set; } = new List<(string, int)>();
        public IReadOnlyList<(string code, int id)> List2 { get; set; } = new List<(string, int)>();

        // Lots of other Lists of type IReadOnlyList<(string, int)>
        // ....

        public int TotalCount
        {
            get
            {

                var allProperties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this).Cast<PropertyDescriptor>();
                var listProperties = allProperties.Where(p => p.PropertyType is IReadOnlyList<(string, int)>).ToList();
                var total = listProperties.Sum(pd => (int)pd.GetValue(this));

                return total;

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Doing this with reflection is going to be quite clumsy. Consider exposing these lists in a manner more convenient for both your `TotalCount` and possibly callers as well, like grouping them all in a `Dictionary` or an `IReadOnlyList` of their own, irrespective of whether you also maintain them as separate properties.

Comment: @JeroenMostert thank you for your reply. Despite your comments I would still like to know what the problem is.

Comment: The problem is that `PropertyType` is of type `Type`, and `Type` is not `IReadOnlyList<...>`. Requisite butt-ugly oneliner: `public int TotalCount => this.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(IReadOnlyList<(string, int)>)).Sum(p => ((IReadOnlyList<(string, int)>) p.GetValue(this)).Count);`. Season with `TypeDescriptor` to taste, where desired.

Comment: @JeroenMostert thanks!